# float:"left" vs display:"inline-block"

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement where a I need to display two divs side by side .This is the basic requirement where I need to build on
many functionalities going further.

I am able to achieve this in two approaches:

Approach 1:

```
<div id="id1" style="width:100%">
  <div id="id2" style="width:100px;color:#0000FF;display:inline-block;border-color: red;border-style: solid;">
  <p>This is some text in a div1 element.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="id3" style="width:100px;display:block;display:inline-block;border-color:blue;border-color: blue;border-style: solid;">
  <p>This is some text in a div2 element.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Approach 2:

```
<div id="id1" style="width:100%">
  <div id="id2" style="width:100px;color:#0000FF;float:left;border-color: red;border-style: solid;">
  <p>This is some text in a div1 element.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="id3" style="width:100px;display:block;float:left;border-color:blue;border-color: blue;border-style: solid;">
  <p>This is some text in a div2 element.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which approach is the better one?

Is it **float:left** ? **display:inline-block**?  *My ultimate aim will be to make divs responsive as well in the future.Thats the reason wanted to know which one is better*
Also, why is there space created between the divs when `display:inline-block` is used?

Comment: This question is either **opinion based** and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements?rq=1

Comment: Very opinion based, besides [`display: flex` is *obviously* the best option](http://jsbin.com/guzevehoya/edit?html,css,output) :p

Comment: In case you are interested, I received a very good answer to a question about float logic - which might help you with your issue as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858717/css-float-logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of using inline blocks is that you can center them horzontally using `text-align: center;' on the container element.

The space you write about is due to whitespace resulting from using line-breaks in the code.